# Waiting on multiple semaphores or multiple message queues

Tags: c, unix, cpu-architecture, blocking, epoll

> In most implementations of UNIX, processes can block on more than one event. That is, rather than waiting on a single semaphore or receiving from a single message queue, the process can wait on multiple semaphores or multiple message queues. What advantage does such a capability offer? How would you implement this?

Now, before everyone starts to ask if this is my school assignment, it is not. It's a recommended exam question for a class I'm taking.

My thoughts on it - something like this:

```
typedef struct QueueElement {
    int Sender;
    int Receiver;
    char Message[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
    int MessageSize;
} QueueElement;

QueueElement MessageQueue[NUM_OF_PROCESSES];



/* Send Message to receiving process queue number */
int SendMsg(int SenderId, int ReceiverId, char* Msg, int Size)
{
    /* Create Queue Element to Enqueue */
    QueueElement El = {
        .Sender = SenderId,
        .Receiver = ...
        .
        .
    };

    /* Enqueue element in queue specified by Receiver's Id */
    Enqueue(&(MessageQueue[ReceiverId]), El);
}



/* Get messages for process defined by ReceiverId, from any queue */
int RecvMsg(int* SenderId, int ReceiverId, char* Msg, int* size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=NUM_OF_PROCESSES; i>=0; i--)
    {
        /* If a message is available for receiving process, Dequeue element from queue */
        if (MessageQueue[i].Receiver = ReceiverId)
        {
            QueueElement El = Dequeue(&(MessageQueue[i]));
            *SenderId = El.Sender;
            strcpy(Msg, El.Message);
            .
            .
            .

            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Now, consider 4 processes running in parallel. They are sending messages to message queues 1, 2, 3, 4 continuously. Now, say all the messages are being sent to process 2. That means process 2 must check for messages in all 4 queues (1, 2, 3, 4). But if new messages are continuously being added, only messages in queue 4 will get processed. How does one get around from starving the other message queues?

Is there a better way to handle this? How do modern architectures handle this? The issue with this solution is that if messages keep getting Enqueued to the high priority Queue (`NUM_OF_PROCESSES`), messages in the lower priority Queues will never get processed.

Comment: re: your edit: unix / POSIX [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) returns the number of FDs that have activity, so you can loop through all the FDs (pipes or sockets or whatever) that have messages before looking for more.  [`poll(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and `epoll` also allow the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to handle this?

Yes. The main problem is that your code continually wastes CPU time polling because it doesn't wait at all.

The better way is to put it in the kernel, such that:

- when a task calls `RecvMsg()`, the kernel can do `if no messages in queue { tell scheduler this task should block until a message is received }` atomically (without race conditions)
- when anything calls `SendMsg()`, the kernel can do `if receiving task is blocked waiting for a message { tell scheduler the receiving task should be unblocked }` atomically (without race conditions)

The next problem is that it only waits for messages. What if you want to wait for a file to be (asynchronously) opened, or wait for a signal, or wait for time to pass, or wait for a mutex to be acquired? For this problem there's two possible solutions:

- have a horrendous mess (e.g. `epoll_pwait()`) with different arguments for different types of things (that still can't be used for some things - e.g. waiting for a mutex).
- implement everything on top of messages so that you only ever have to wait for a message.

For the second solution; you mostly end up replacing traditional procedural programming with the actor model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Yes of course, the actual queuing and process blocking/unblocking mechanisms will be handled by the kernel. The process will have to do something like a supervisor call to pass control to the kernel. This code was written more so to explain what I'm trying to comprehend. 

The main problem with the code I posted is that lower priority message queue elements might never get processed if higher priority queue is always getting new messages. This is a consequence of the `descending for loop` in the code. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @ImranNiloy: Under normal conditions you don't want to get around that (you don't want to waste time doing less important work for lower priority messages when you could/should be doing more important work handling higher priority messages). If there's always higher priority messages then it indicates a malicious attacker (e.g. a "denial of service" flood of messages), flow control bugs (sender is sending messages too fast) or inadequate scalability (not enough receivers working in parallel to handle load); where the solution is to fix the sender (not the receiver).

Comment: @ImranNiloy: Note that (regardless of message priority or order messages are handled) if the receiver can't keep up then the message queues will continue growing until you run out of RAM and have to take drastic action (e.g. terminate the process to free many GiB of memory tied up in message queue/s). Alternatively, as a last resort (to guard against malicious attackers and design flaws in sender and receiver) kernel might throttle/delay sender when receiver's queue is too full. Of course the problem can also be the receiver (e.g. the "task is not responding" dialog box thing in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code answers the question the way the asker intends. To expand on what the question is asking:

Normally you can call something like `read()` to read from a file descriptor and it'll block until some data comes in. What if you have multiple file descriptors, though, and you want to block on all of them simultaneously until data comes in on any of them? You can't do that with a simple `read()` which only takes a single file descriptor.

- What kind of API would you need? Show a function or set of functions that would let someone read from multiple sources at the same time.

**Hint:** [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) does exactly this. Good keywords to google include "select", "multiplexing", and "non-blocking I/O".

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Could you recommend a simple implementation of this, built from ground up? In the course I'm taking, we are more so concerned about handling messages from hardware interrupts originating from components with varying priorities.

Answer (score 0):

When different priority message queues are used, reader will continue serving high priority queue and when that gets exhausted, it will move to lower priority queue. In case priorities are not used, threads can be used to serve queues in parallel but it will not guarantee the sequence in which messages appear on different queues.